# Regex to match Auth keys in wp-config

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress

Could anyone advise on how best to match the following in my `wp-config.php` with a `regex`

```
define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = "define('AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here');'";
$string .= 'define("SECURE_AUTH_KEY",         "put your unique phrase here");';
$string .= 'define("LOGGED_IN_KEY",         \'put your unique phrase here\');';
preg_match_all("/define\s*\(\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"]\s*,\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"]\s*\)/", $string, $matches);
var_export($matches);
```

Hey, it's hard to read and looks like Perl, I feel at home!

That will yield

```
array (
  0 =>
  array (
    0 => 'define(\'AUTH_KEY\',         \'put your unique phrase here\')',
    1 => 'define("SECURE_AUTH_KEY",         "put your unique phrase here")',
    2 => 'define("LOGGED_IN_KEY",         \'put your unique phrase here\')',
  ),
  1 =>
  array (
    0 => 'AUTH_KEY',
    1 => 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',
    2 => 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',
  ),
  2 =>
  array (
    0 => 'put your unique phrase here',
    1 => 'put your unique phrase here',
    2 => 'put your unique phrase here',
  ),
)
```

Basically, this assumes that in both strings, there will be neither ' nor ", those will be only used to start and end strings. It will work by accident on weird things like `define("myKey', 'test')`, but those are probably not an issue, as PHP won't like to compile them.

By the way, you could avoid using a regexp by simply including the wp_config.php and then saying `print LOGGED_IN_KEY`.

Answer (score 1):

There is very useful regex tester https://regex101.com/r/gmlGpT/1

```
define\(['"][A-Z_]+['"]\,\s+['"](?<key>[\w\s]+)['"]\);
```